# criteria for lookup

Tags: workflow, opportunity, lookup, account

I created a lookup for sales people in the opportunity objects and I want them to be grouped according to the picklist in the account. However, when I create a lookup, the criteria should only be in the opportunity or in the sales people object. How can I achieve this? I have tried formula and workflow but when I click the magnifying in the criteria the formula field or the field I use for field update workflow is not in the list.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't traverse or use related(lookup or master) object in the lookup criteria. if you want to use account information , then create formula field to get account information on opp.

```
Administrators specify the restrictions by configuring filter criteria that compare fields and values on:

    The current record (source)
    The lookup object (target)
    The user's record, permissions, and role
    Records directly related to the target object
```